# send data & ether to other contract in the same method

Tags: solidity, remix

I need to call a function from another contract 
(the function take a parameter and need 1 Ether to execute) like this:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
    contract ContractONE {    
       uint public i;
       function register(uint _i) payable{
          if(msg.value > 1 ether){
             i = _i;
          } else {revert();}
        }
       ...
    }
```

............................................

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
  import "./ContractONE.sol";
  Contract contractTwo {

     address addofContract1;
     uint i ;
     ....
     function changeNum(uint _i) payable{
         i = _i;
         ContractONE c = ContractONE(addofContract1);
         //// problem here:
         c.register(_i); //will revert, cause it does not send ether!!
        ////
      }
    }
```

the second Contract has already some Ether in it.

is there a method to do that? maybe like `c.register(_i).transfer(amount)!` 
 or a trick with `addofContract1.call(.....,.....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer

```
c.register.value(msg.value)(_i);
```